# VBA error handler in Worksheet_Change event

Tags: excel, error-handling, runtime-error, excel-2013, vba

I have hit a bit of a stumbling block.

I would like to know how i would build an error handler to prevent a run time error. I accidentally typed in a non numerical number into the named cell `ProductNumber`  and got a debug

**This is the worksheet change code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("People_working_on_Campaign")) Is Nothing Then
        Toggle_Rows
    Else
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("ProductNumber")) Is Nothing Then
        Toggle_Rows2
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

**These are the macros i am using for each cell**

```
Sub Toggle_Rows()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROI Calculator")
    Dim val As Integer

    val = Sheets("ROI Calculator").Range("People_working_on_Campaign").Value

    Select Case Sheet.Range("People_working_on_Campaign").Value2
        Case 1 To 10
            Sheet.Rows("45:59").Hidden = True
            Sheet.Rows(45).Resize(Sheet.Range("People_working_on_Campaign").Value2).Hidden = False
    End Select

End Sub

Sub Toggle_Rows2()
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet: Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ROI Calculator")
    Dim val As Integer

    val = Sheets("ROI Calculator").Range("ProductNumber").Value

    Select Case Sheet.Range("ProductNumber").Value2
        Case 1 To 9
            Sheet.Rows("4:12").Hidden = True
            Sheet.Rows(4).Resize(Sheet.Range("ProductNumber").Value2).Hidden = False
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the lines saying `val = ...` - they aren't being used and (I assume) are the source of your error.  You have your `Select Case` statement set up in such a way that it will ignore any non-numeric values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an error handler introduce some validation to your code. You can check:

- if the input value `IsNumeric`
- if yes then do the `Select Case...` logic
- if not then do something else

I did a quick re-write of your code.

- In `Worksheet_Change` you can pass the `Range` to the sub routine to prevent needing to re-define it.
- In the sub routines, define the variable for the cell value as a `Variant` meaning it can accept any data type. Then you can use `IsNumeric` to check that the input as a number and use `CLng` to get the integer for the `Select Case...` logic.

**Worksheet_Change**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' set a reference to worksheet of Target and use it below
    Set ws = Target.Worksheet

    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("People_working_on_Campaign")) Is Nothing Then
        Toggle_Rows Target
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("ProductNumber")) Is Nothing Then
        Toggle_Rows2 Target
    End If

End Sub
```

**Sub routines**

```
Option Explicit

' rng is going to be People_working_on_Campaign
Sub Toggle_Rows(rng As Range)

    Dim var As Variant

    ' get value of range
    var = rng.Value

    ' test if range is numeric
    If IsNumeric(var) Then
        ' test range value - CLng will convert to Long which is preferred to Integer
        Select Case CLng(var)
            Case 1 To 10
                rng.Worksheet.Rows("45:59").Hidden = True
                rng.Worksheet.Rows(45).Resize(rng.Value2).Hidden = False
            Case Else
                ' do something else ?
         End Select
    Else
        MsgBox "You should enter an integer to People_working_on_Campaign"
    End If

End Sub

' rng will be ProductNumber
Sub Toggle_Rows2(rng As Range)

    Dim var As Variant

    ' get value of range
    var = rng.Value

    ' test if range is numeric
    If IsNumeric(var) Then
        ' test range value - CLng will convert to Long which is preferred to Integer
        Select Case CLng(var)
            Case 1 To 9
                rng.Worksheet.Rows("4:12").Hidden = True
                rng.Worksheet.Rows(4).Resize(rng.Value2).Hidden = False
            Case Else
                ' do something else ?
         End Select
    Else
        MsgBox "You should enter an integer to ProductNumber"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: FWIW - You can remove `Dim var As Variant` `var = rng.Value` because `var` isn't being used.